# Finding the closest values above and below a certain date by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of longitudinal measurements and am looking to find the closest measurements that were taken both above and below a certain date. My date column is coded as the number of days since the beginning of the study.

For each participant, I want to find the one measurement that is the closest value BELOW 100 days of the study and the one measurement that is the closest value ABOVE 100 days of the study. If the participant has a measurement at 100 days, then I want that value returned.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data_frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
measures = c(10, 11, 11.4, 11.7, 11.8, 4.1, 4.3, 4.7, 13.3, 13.2, 13.5, 13.9, 14, 14.1),
days = c(5, 45, 60, 94, 104, 21, 76, 115, 10, 26, 73, 100, 132, 154))

df
# id measures days
# 1     10       5
# 1     11      45
# 1     11.4    60
# 1     11.7    94
# 1     11.8   104
# 2      4.1    21
# 2      4.3    76
# 2      4.7   115
# 3     13.3    10
# 3     13.2    26
# 3     13.5    73
# 3     13.9   100
# 3     14     132
# 3     14.1   154
```

For ID 1, I want it to return days 94 and 104 and measurements 11.7 and 11.8. For ID 2, I want it to return days 76 and 115 and measurements 4.3 and 4.7. For ID 3, I want it to return day 100 twice and measurement 13.9 twice.

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
summarise(below = max(df$days[df$days <= 100]),
          above = min(df$days[df$days >= 100]),
          below_msrmt = df$measures[which(df$days == below)],
          above_msrmt = df$measures[which(df$days == above)])
```

But it looks like the code isn't reading the group_by argument because it keeps giving me this:

```
# id below above below_msrmt above_msrmt
# 1    100   100        13.9        13.9
# 2    100   100        13.9        13.9
# 3    100   100        13.9        13.9
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the `df$`, it works because `df$days` or `df$measures` selects the entire column and not just the values of that columns within each group.  Thus, we get same value for all groups as it is the summarised value for the entire column

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(below = max(days[days <= 100]),
      above = min(days[days >= 100]),
      below_msrmt = measures[which(days == below)],
      above_msrmt = measures[which(days == above)])
```

Comment: Oh wow, THANK YOU. I have been struggling with this for so long. Do you know why removing the df$ fixes the problem?